# How to expand the descriptions of annotations

Tags: interface, customization, annotation

I'm currently working on modifying a 3D model of armour for someone, who has used annotations to describe the kind of detail they want and where. Some of the descriptions for the annotations are longer than what fit in the boxes and thus end with "...".
[image: Blender Annotation Expansion]
It seems the person I am working on this for doesn't have a list of the full descriptions and I cannot acquire any more info on them, aside from what is in Blender. How does one find the full description of an annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view your annotation names in *Outliner > Blender File > Grease Pencil*
Use Middle Mouse Button to scroll sideways.

<sup>(Annotation names allow 128 characters max ;))</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that!